# don't run JS in erb unless called

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a page with an ajax GET to a ruby function.
the Get request should return the variable @player.
when the ajax is "success" it should call the function popPools

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  data: { faceid : response.id },
  url: "/pool/mMypools2",
  success: popPools()
  })


function popPools(){
  $("<%= content_tag(:p, @player[0].id) %>"
  ).appendTo(document.getElementById("asd"));}
```

my problem is that the function popPools is being called automatically before the ajax has a chance to get the new variables from mMypools response.

```
error:
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

because onload @player contain nothing.

thank you

Comment: I'd suggest you to read a little bit more of javascript. You can check some here: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from the end of `popPools`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  data: { faceid : response.id },
  url: "/pool/mMypools2",
  success: popPools
  })
```

You were passing the *result* of the popPools function as the value for `success` rather than the function itself.

Comment: thank you, i tried it.
this way the function is not called at all from the ajax request.

is it really the way it suppose to be? im not mistaken right? the server should send the new variables from mMypools2 to the client side?

Comment: I don't actually know RoR very well...I answered your question because the problem seemed to be the Javascript. If popPools isn't being called after the modification I suggested, that means that the Ajax request wasn't successful. Try watching it in Firebug to see what the actual Ajax request and response contain (my guess is you'll probably see some sort of error with the response which will hopefully give you a clue).

Comment: I just looked at your example again and noticed something obvious that I missed... `$("<%= content_tag(:p, @player[0].id) %>")` might be a problem. Unless it returns the exact jQuery selector you need...just remember that jQuery knows nothing about ERB, so what you're aiming to do is construct a valid selector that jQuery will understand, via ERB.

Comment: Also, the whole point of jQuery is to avoid lengthy Javascript like `document.getElementById` - just use $('#your_id_goes_here'). I'd recommend reading up on jQuery basics.

Comment: thank you Matt B.
every thing is working now, i made the changes you suggested, but the page is still running the function popPools without me calling it.

about the content_tag - this is the way to dynamically create new html tags with rails, this part will work once the function will be called manually and not automatically (checked it whilest debuging).

Comment: The only way popPools would be running without you calling it is if that `$.ajax()` function is being called. So maybe the Ajax function is running before you think it is...did you put all the jQuery code inside a `$(document).ready()` callback? If not then the Ajax request could be running before your element even exists on the page. Again, I highly recommend reading up on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do too much in the response template.  The Ajax code really belongs at the controller level because its trying to get data out of your application.  The template should be left "dumb" and just respond to the variables that are passed to it.

To fix this I would move the top of your file out of the response template completely.  Once you have properly loaded @player at the controller level, then proceed with your response.  Oh, and don't forget to Javascript escape the resultant HTML or any quotes that come back the `content_tag` function will break the jQuery.

*file.js.erb:*

```
$(
  "<%= j content_tag(:p, @player[0].id) %>"
 ).appendTo(document.getElementById("asd"));}
```

I hope this advice helps.

Comment: thank you it is helpful, thou i can not get it from the controller because i need to wait for facebook to send me back the token and response. only than i can call the controller with the Faceid.